# Animate text in div element together with Raphael SVG element

Tags: javascript, animation, html, text, raphael

I would like to get a button-like object consisting of a SVG rectangle as the background and HTML text in the foreground. The Raphael SVG library offers nice possibilities to create, modify and animate SVG elements.

I [found a solution](https://github.com/kreynolds/RaphaelJS-Infobox) to draw HTML text in a DIV element along/over the Raphael objects. How can I use the animating methods from Raphael to make the text move with the background?

I am only interested in basic 2D movement, no rotation or deformation ...
I know I could use SVG text element which is supported by Raphael, but this does not allow me text-wrapping, text-styling (css). I was tried unsuccessfully to find a method to get the coordinates of the animated object during animation.

Here is some sample code in coffeescript inspired by the above example mad eby Kelley Reynolds. My problem is how to synchronize thy movement of the background with the overlaying div :

```
nodeBox = (paper, params, attrs) ->
params = params or {}
attrs = attrs or {}
@paper = paper
@x = params.x or 0
@y = params.y or 0
@width = params.width or @paper.width
@height = params.height or @paper.height
@xMargin = params.xMargin or 5
@yMargin = params.yMargin or 5
@rounding = params.rounding or 0
@backgBox = this.paper.rect(@x-@xMargin, @y-@yMargin, @width+2*@xMargin, @height+2*@yMargin, this.rounding).attr(attrs)
containerId = @backgBox.node.parentNode.parentNode.id
containerId = containerId or @backgBox.node.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id
@container = jQuery('#' + containerId)

@div = jQuery('<div style="position: absolute; overflow: auto; width: 0; height: 0;"></div>').insertAfter(@container)
jQuery(document).bind('ready', this, (event) ->
    event.data.update()
    )
jQuery(window).bind('resize', this, (event) ->
    event.data.update()
    )
return this

# update function
nodeBox::update = () ->
offset = @container.offset()
@div.css(
    'top': (@y + (@rounding) + (offset.top)) + 'px',
    'left': (@x + (@rounding) + (offset.left)) + 'px',
    'height': (@height - (@rounding*2) + 'px'),
    'width': (@width - (@rounding*2) + 'px')
)

# animate function
nodeBox::animate = (attrs, duration, type) ->
    @backgBox.animate(attrs, duration, type)
    ###
    Animation of the  div ???
    ###

$(document).ready ->
paper = new Raphael document.getElementById('canvas_container'), '100%', '100%'
node1 = new nodeBox(paper, x:200, y:200, width:200, height:60, rounding: 10, xMargin: 8, yMargin: 4, 'showBorder': true).attr(fill: 'lightblue', stroke: '#3b4449', 'stroke-width': 3)
node1.div.html('This is some crazy content that goes inside of that box that will wrap around.')
node1.div.css('font-family': 'Helvetica','font-size': 16, 'text-align': 'justify')

# animate :
node1.animate({x: moveX}, 1000, 'bounce')
```

Comment: Please provide code or jsfiddle example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured this out by myself. First possibility is to use the eve library, which already comes with Raphael 2.x. You can update the coordinates of the div on every frame of the animation corresponding to the coordinates of the background-box using eve.on() :

```
nodeBox::animate = (attrs, duration, type) ->

offset = @canvasContainer.offset()
strokeWidth = @backgBox.attrs['stroke-width']
textBox = @div
rounding = @rounding
xMargin = @xMargin
yMargin = @yMargin

### we animate the underlying box
@backgBox.animate(attrs, duration, type, eve.unbind('raphael.anim.frame.' + @backgBox.id, onAnimate))

    ### the coordinates of the div are updated on every frame
eve.on('raphael.anim.frame.' + @backgBox.id, onAnimate = (animationObject) ->
    textBox.css(
        'top': (@attrs.y + (rounding) + (yMargin) + (offset.top) + strokeWidth) + 'px',
        'left': (@attrs.x + (rounding) + (xMargin) +  (offset.left) + strokeWidth) + 'px', # scrollbar width
        'height': (@attrs.height - (rounding*2) - (yMargin*2) - strokeWidth + 'px'),
        'width': (@attrs.width - (rounding*2) - (xMargin*2) - strokeWidth + 'px')
        )
    )
```

The downside of this solution is, that it does not feel very smooth, one can already see the text "following" the box. Therefore I am no trying the GreenSock Animation Platform which comes with an plugin for Raphael and should offer synchronous animation of the vector graphics and the overlying DOM. [Take a look here](http://forums.greensock.com/topic/6059-animating-raphaeljs-elements-with-v12-js/)